# Is it possible to use EJB2.1 and EJB 3.1 in the same project

Tags: ejb

We have an old project written with EJB 2.1. Now we need to extend the project with the new requirements. But i don't want to use the old complicated EJB 2 again.

Is it possible to use EJB3.1/JPA in an existing project written with EJB 2.1.

P.S. Application Server is WebSphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to reference EJB 3 from EJB 2. The older EJB applications can be deployed as is on EJB3.0 container since pre-EJB3.0 APIs are available in EJB3.0. Check these links out for detailed information:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/321218/EJB-JEE/java/EJB-call-EJB

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ReferenceEJB3BeansFromEJB2Beans

A clean migration from EJB 2 to EJB 3 would be a better design choice though.

Comment: what is your experience about the migration. would it be easy?

Comment: I've never experienced such migration to be honest because my company still uses EJB 2.0. A little search however, proved me that there are plenty of useful sources on the web (sources, discussions, etc) about the migration. Such attempt would probably be a bit challenging but those sources would help for sure.